# when we create any objecet why we need to create base class of one class and instance of another class?

Tags: c#-4.0, overriding

Consider below code example

```
class BC
{
  public virtual void Display()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("BC::Display");
  }
}

class DC : BC
{
  public override void Display()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("DC::Display");
  }
}

class TC : DC
{
  public override void Display()
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine("TC::Display");
  }
}

class Demo
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     BC b;
     b = new BC();
     b.Display();    

     b = new DC();
     b.Display();    

     b = new TC();
     b.Display();    
  }
}
```

Output

```
BC::Display
DC::Display
TC::Display
```

In this code example you can look at 
instnace of DC is created of base class BC  AND
instance of TC is created of base class BC
e.g
**BC b=new DC(); BC b=new TC();**

So why we need this?

Comment: @bourne:i am not asking about inheritance.I have doubt with ** BC b=new DC(); BC b=new TC() **

Answer (score 0):

This is needed to not tie code to an implementation. This makes the application resistant to changes i.e. you don't have to refactor your entire application to incorporate new changes because you are coding to an interface and not to an implementation.

Also inheritance provide code reusability by avoiding duplication.

Comment: @Rahul As mentioned before you need this to avoid change in the application when new Displays are added.

Comment: So you can basically have a display(BC b) method which can be passed any instance of a class which inherits from BC and the display method will call the method of the correct instance.